# Handling heavy deletions/insertions in Core Data

Tags: ios, multithreading, macos, core-data

I'm dealing with a scenario where there are objects which, were they to be deleted, would cause an exponential amount of deletions through cascade-delete relationships. In this way, deleting 20 of these objects can result in ~3,000 objects ultimately being deleted. This can cause for very slow saves, if performed with the main context.

To combat this, I'm creating a 'worker' context that uses the same persistent store as the main context, making changes there, then saving the worker context and merging those changes with the main context:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *workerContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];

workerContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = mainContext.persistentStoreCoordinator;

[notificationCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(workerContextDidSave:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:workerContext];

//  Here I do a 'superficial' deletion on the main context, so the UI updates,
//  but do the actual deletion on the worker context. Then I save the worker context:

[workerContext save:nil];

// Which fires spawnedWorkerContextDidSave:, where I merge changes to the main context:

[mainContext performBlockAndWait:^{
    [mainContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
}];
```

My question(s) are: what's the most common way of handling these kinds of large deletion batches? Are there any pitfalls to my approach above? Additionally, the merge causes some small lag on the main thread, but nothing near where it was when I did the deletions and save on the main thread.

Comment: try to use  GCD not in main thread.

Comment: @SunilSingh That's essentially what I'm doing here. The worker context is using it's own thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach of deleting data via a second context is fine.

You may find it works faster if you first prefetch the data: simply execute a fetch request for the objects you will delete in the background context, and set the relationships to prefetch. This will pull data into the row cache (memory) before you delete, which can save trips to the disk.

If you find that the delay merging the changes on the main thread is a problem, you can instead consider just resetting the main context. The downside there is that your app has to refetch all its data. You could, for example, fire notifications to warn different parts of the app that the reset is a) going to happen, and b) has happened.

Lastly, there is now API in Core Data for performing large deletes in the background without pulling data into memory. The main downside there is you have to be careful to merge the deleted objects yourself, because the context will not know they have been deleted.

Comment: Thanks Drew! I'll give your suggestions a try, especially the prefetch one.